# Proving the Population Mean Squared Error formula from Greene (7th Ed)

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability

On page 93 of Greene 7th edition, there is a statement:

MSE $= E_yE_x[y - x'\gamma]^2$ can be written as $E_{y,x} \{ y-E[y|x] \}^2 + E_{y,x} \{ E[y|x]-x'\gamma] \}^2$.

In order for this to be true, the middle term of the quadratic must somehow cancel out. This is my (failed) attempt at proving that part:

WTS: $E_yE_x[2(y - E_y(y|x)) (E_y(y|x) - x'\gamma) ]= 0$. Dropping the 2 in front:

$ E_yE_x[(y - E_y(y|x)) (E_y(y|x) - x'\gamma) ]$

$= E_yE_x[ y E_y(y|x)- E_y(y|x)^2 -y x'\gamma + E_y(y|x) x'\gamma] $

$=E_x[ E_y(y)E_y(y|x) - E_y(y|x)^2 - E_y(y)x'\gamma +E_y(y|x)x'\gamma  ]$

Using $E_y(y) = E_x(E_y(y|x))$ LIE on the first and third terms:

$=E_x[ E_x(E_y(y|x))E_y(y|x) - E_y(y|x)^2 - E_x(E_y(y|x))x'\gamma +E_y(y|x)x'\gamma  ]$

Now at this point, let's focus on the first 2 terms. They look similar so I tried to cancel them out:

$=E_x[ E_x(E_y(y|x))E_y(y|x) - E_y(y|x)^2 $

Now distributing out the outer most expectation:

$=E_x(E_y(y|x))E_x(E_y(y|x)) - E_x( E_y(y|x)^2 )$.

At this point I am stuck. One is expectation squred and the next is expectation of squared. They are not the same. Could someone tell me where I am going awry? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: what is $E[y - x^\prime\gamma\mid x]$?  Another hint: the notation obscures the simplicity of this result.  Work directly with expectations, rather than conditional expectations, and relate $E[(X-\mu)^2]$ to $E[(X-a)^2]$ and $(\mu-a)^2$ when $X$ is any random variable with $E[X]=\mu$ and $a$ is any number.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the first hint? Without the conditional part, the proof is easy I think. It's precisely because of the presence of conditional part that I find myself stuck...